# Find device by Hardware ID in Device Manager?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, device-manager

Is there a way to search through the Windows 10 Device Manager, e.g. by Hardware ID? (Or is there another tool that can do this?)

I know (part of) the Hardware ID of a device I have, e.g. it starts with "USB\VID_1C88". My suspicion is that this device is causing trouble, so I want to uninstall all drivers associated with it.

Comment: Device Manager have no tool which searches over device properties. Look in registry,  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\DriverDatabase\DeviceIds\USB`.

Comment: Thanks @Akina, it is kinda hard to go from the registry information back to the device manager, but doable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are websites, I've listed at the bottom, that archive H/W ID's so that COULD provide insight as well as an app. nirsoft [DevManView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html) & [USBDeview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) can do this under a column called 'Instance ID'. Apparently USBDeview can show historical devices that are disconnected as well. I don't know nirsoft, his tools are just my go to :)
[image: nirsoft devmanview]

- http://www.linux-usb.org/usb-ids.html
- https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/
- https://www.pcilookup.com/
- https://devicehunt.com/
- https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131022/how-to-find-drivers-for-devices-using-a-hardware-id

Comment: DevManView is perfect! It allows sorting on HW ID, shows disconnected devices, and can uninstall drivers. Thanks for nirsoft!

Comment: I'm practicing powershell & found a built-in way to do this: `Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object InstanceId -Like "USB\VID_1*"` to get more details do this: `Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object InstanceId -Like "USB\VID_1*" | Format-List`. Shorthand/alias: `Get-PnpDevice | Where InstanceId -Like "USB\VID_1*" | fl`. Other useful commands (aka how I found this & learn): `help *dev*`; `help Get-PnpDevice -ShowWindow`; `get-command *dev*`. Also there is a `Get-PnpDeviceProperty` cmdlet which may provide more details, no idea what it does yet

Comment: Just found a way to export Device Properties Details tab info seen in Device Manager. I even did it for a disconnected digital camera: `Get-PnpDevice -InstanceId "USB\VID_0979*" | Get-PnpDeviceProperty | Export-Csv DevDetails.csv`

Answer (score 7):

I used a tool called [`Hardware Identify`](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/hardware-identify/) . It lists all installed hardware devices on the computer and displays information about each device. You could check the device name by Hardware ID like this below:
[image]

Comment: That is certainly a useful tool. It only shows devices actually attached though. So any disconnected USB device will not show up, even if the drivers are installed :-(.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice little tool from Microsoft that lets you list all devices called
[Devcon (Device Console)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon). In combination with Powershell it is quite easy to identify devices e.g.

```
 devcon64.exe hwids * | Select-String "YOUR HARDWARE ID" -Context 5
```

[Devcon is available as portable app on Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/devcon.portable)

Comment: [I guess Microsoft doesn't recommend using devcon anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-migration). I think this is the replacement for [pnputil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-examples) command built-into-windows: `pnputil /enum-devices`